# Cannot return and assign char array to pointer in C

Tags: c

```
    char *test = "hello";

    test = change_test("world");

    printf("%s",test);

char* change_test(char *n){
    printf("change: %s",n);

    return n;
}
```

im trying to pass a 'string' back to a char pointer using a function but get the following error:

assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function used without forward declaration will be considered having signature `int (...)`. You should either forward-declare it:

```
char* change_test(char*);
...
  char* test = "hello";
  // etc.
```

or just move the definition `change_test` *before* where you call it.

Answer (score 1):

printf() prints the text to the console but does not change n. Use this code instead:

```
char *change_test(char *n)  {
    char *result = new char[256];
    sprintf(result, "change: %s", n);
    return result;
}
// Do not forget to call delete[] on the value returned from change_test
```

Also add the declaration of change_test() before calling it:

```
char *change_test(char *n);
```

Comment: 1. Let's hope n points to a string of less than 248 characters.  2. this is C not C++.  There's no `new`, try `malloc()`/`calloc()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting an integer to a pointer somewhere. Your code is incomplete, but at a guess I'd say it's that you're not defining `change_test()` before you use it, so the C compiler guesses at its type (and assumes it returns an integer.) Declare `change_test()` before calling it, like so:

```
char *change_test(char *n);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a bunch guys! didnt think i would have this problem solved by lunch. here is the final test class

```
/* standard libraries */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* change_test(char*);


int main(){

    char *test = "hello";
    test = change_test("world");
    printf("%s",test);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

char* change_test(char *n){
    return n;
}
```